# Как преобразовать число из 10 в 16 систему с определённой длиной строки

Tags: c#

есть десятичное число и его как то надо преобразовать в 16 сс с определённой длинной строки.
Пробовал вот так вот:

```
Convert.ToString("число",16)
```

но как задать длину строки не понятно.
пример такого метода есть в delphi с его IntToHex("число","Длинна")

Comment: А десятичное число в какой форме? Если в виде строки, то конвертируй её в число и число уже форматируй с помощью этого формата: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#XFormatString

Comment: и тебе спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n1 = 12345;

// hex, width = 5
string s1 = $"{n1,5:X}";

// hex, width = 5, with leading nulls
string s2 = $"{n1:X5}";
```

Comment: спасибо тебе умный человек

Comment: В кучу `Convert.ToString("число",16).PadLeft(5)`, `.PadLeft('0', 5)`